# when set background image in div at time i have to give static height of div otherwise it not take automatic height

Tags: html, css

When I `set` the `background image` at I have to give it a `static size` of div otherwise it will not display the background images. What is problem.....

[image: Here ist a Screenshot of the Problem]

I have this **CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto !important;
}   
.main_div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
}   
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image:url(file:///D|/HJ/ALL%20HTML%20TEMP/bootstrap/bootstrap/img/header_bg.jpg);
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Background images have no effect on the dimensions of the element. That's just the way it works I'm afraid.

Comment: Who edits this stuff and doesn't fix the wording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you float the `.main_div` with `width:100%`? Floated elements get out of the flow which means they don't stretch their parent elements, so a background set on `.main_div`'s parent won't show.

You should either remove the `float` or add some clearing technique to the `header` (also known as a c[ss clearfix](http://davidwalsh.name/css-clear-fix)). See demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/YLEgY/1/

Answer (score 1):

The first comment is correct, I decided to create a little demo to explain this.

So if you take a look at the demo you can see we have the first `div` using `background` to place an image. This is fine and valid `CSS` but without a height and width how can the background be displayed?

Moving onto the second `div`, here we give the `div` with the `background` and height/width. Now the background has appeared. Because we have defined the height and width the background has room to display. A `background` cannot tell the element to be a certain size without you defining it.

And the last `div`, this has `<img>` inside of it. As this is an `block` element it has a height and width, so it will show the image as the parent has no height or width and therefore will allow the image to expand inside of it.

### HTML:

```
With no height:
<div class="image"></div>With height:
<div class="imageWH"></div>With img:
<div class="imageIMG">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.image {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat;
}
.imageWH {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
}
.imageIMG {
    <!-- No need for anything -->
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7LGVA/)